# Geometric transformation: reproducing the Gimp warp tool in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, gimp

I would like to reproduce the Gimp warp tool in python, specifically the "Grow" transformation.

For example, having the input image:

[image]

I would like to obtain:

[image]

This is a template for the code that I want to write:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from operator import itemgetter

def growth_area(in_img, parameters):
    #in_img comes from cv2.imread('./test_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    size, strength, hardness, position = itemgetter('size', 'strength', 'hardness', 'position')(parameters) 
    img_out = np.zeros(in_img.shape, dtype=in_img.dtype)
    rows, cols = in_img.shape
    # Here I want to implement the code 
    # to get the transformation shown in 
    # the pictures, and show the result in img_out
    cv2.imshow('warp', img_out)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

I would like to control the execution of the `growth_area()` with the 4 parameters `'size', 'strength', 'hardness', 'position'`, where the first 3 parameters behave as the 3 parameters in Gimp, and the last one `'position'` represent the center of the transformation. How can I implement this?

Comment: Define what those arguments are supposed to do with respect to the warping?  Can you give a mathematical description of the warp?

Comment: Is this really the Warp Tool? or is it `Filters > Map > Warp`?  But what you show looks more like `Filters > Distorts > Whirl & Pinch` with a 0° rotation and a negative pinch.

Comment: Isn't GIMP open source? Have a look at what they are doing ...

Comment: I have just tried `Filters > Map > Warp` and the result is similar to the one that I want to get. The image that I posted is obtained applying several times this transformation
https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-warp.html
with the `grow` option, shown in  figure 14.165. This tool has the same parameters that I gave to the python function. I don't have a mathematical description and the biggest problem is that I can't find a definition online. I am currently trying to look at the gimp sources.